# What locks are involved when moving data from table to another in SQLServer?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, locking

I have two tables. 
Let's call one, **Released** and the other **Previous**.
All updates are done on the Released table in real time, as and when they occur, through out the day.

The Previous table is basically an archive of older records in the Released table. That means, I intend to copy data older than a **period** in Released to Previous and then delete those records from Released.

If I were to write a SQL Server job to move older data from the Released to the Previous table, what sort of locks would be involved? Would such a process slow down writes to the Released table? If it does then how do I minimize such a negative impact?

PS: All updates to Released are done by the application code, via entity framework. I've worked with other Relational databases, but I'm new to SQL Server. So I've gone through https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213039%28v=sql.80%29.aspx to get an idea of the types of locks in SQL Server.

Comment: when you delete same record you have just a table lock

Comment: If you use table partitioning its possible you'll have no locks.

Comment: but then you'd have to keep recreating partitions every once in a while. does that help?

Comment: @EakanGopalakrishnan, yes, you will need to maintain a sliding window to use a partition `SWITCH` but the advantage is the partition move is a nearly instantaneous meta data operation. Without partitioning, you can use `DELETE` with an `OUTPUT` clause to move data.  This will acquire exclusive locks on the rows (including index rows) being moved.  Concurrency depends much on the indexes.  A clustered index on the date being used for the archive and no other indexes would be ideal.

Comment: would there be a downtime involved when using the sliding window partition strategy? or is it seamless for end users who might be querying/updating the table in question.